# Need to get JSON response for role and permission matrix created using JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get the  JSON response on saving the role and permission matrix created using JSON object.

This is my code to create the role and permission matrix (table):

```
 <table id="perm">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Permissions</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $table = $( "#perm" );
    var $tHead = $table.find( ".header" );
    var permissions = ['',"R", "W", "D", "WS" ]
    // Count and add Roles 
    var roles = [];
    var numRoles = 0;
    for( i in obj ) {
        if( roles[ obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID ] == undefined ) {
            roles[ obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID ] = obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID;
            numRoles++;
            $tHead.append( '<th colspan="4" class="role_' + obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID + '">' + obj[ i ].RoleName + '</th>' );
        }
    }
    // Load table
    for( i in obj ) {
        var element = obj[ i ];
        // Add screen row
        if( $table.find( "tr.row_" + element.ScreenID ).length == 0 ) {
            $table.append( '<tr class="row_' + element.ScreenID + '"><td>' + element.ScreenName + '</td></tr>' );
            $row = $table.find( '.row_' + element.ScreenID );
            for( j in roles ) {
                var role = roles[ j ];
                for( k = 1; k < 5; k++ ) {
                    var uniqueCheck = "check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + role + "_" + k;
                    $row.append( '<td class="cell_' + role + '"><input id="' + uniqueCheck + '" name="' + uniqueCheck + '" type="checkbox"> ' + permissions[ k ] + ' </td>' );
                }
            }
        }
        var checkId = "#check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + element.ProjectRoleID + "_" + element.PermissiontypeID;
        $( checkId ).attr( "checked", "checked" );
    }
});
```

This is my matrix (Table):

[image]

I need to get the values of  checked check boxes. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `$(uniqueCheck).is(":checked")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Slight Modification of your code

```
  var $table = $("#perm");
        var $tHead = $table.find(".header");
        var permissions = ['', "R", "W", "D", "WS"]
        // Count and add Roles 
        var roles = [];
        var numRoles = 0;
        for (i in obj) {
            if (roles[obj[i].ProjectRoleID] == undefined && obj[i].ProjectRoleID != null) {
                roles[obj[i].ProjectRoleID] = obj[i].ProjectRoleID;
                numRoles++;
                $tHead.append('<th colspan="4" value = "' + obj[i].ProjectRoleID + '" class="role_' + obj[i].ProjectRoleID + '">' + obj[i].RoleName + '</th>');
            }
        }
        // Load table
        for (i in obj) {
            var element = obj[i];
            // Add screen row
            if (element.ScreenID != null) {
                if ($table.find("tr.row_" + element.ScreenID).length == 0) {
                    $table.append('<tr class="Permission row_' + element.ScreenID + '" value = "' + element.ScreenID + '"><td>' + element.ScreenName + '</td></tr>');
                    $row = $table.find('.row_' + element.ScreenID);
                    for (j in roles) {
                        var role = roles[j];
                        for (k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
                            var uniqueCheck = "check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + role + "_" + permissions[k];
                            $row.append('<td class="cell_' + role + '"><input id="' + uniqueCheck + '"  name="' + permissions[k] + '" type="checkbox" value = "' + role + '"> ' + permissions[k] + ' </td>');
                        }
                    }

                }
                var checkId = "#check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + element.ProjectRoleID + "_" + element.PermissionType;
                $(checkId).attr("checked", "checked");
            }
        }
```

// Here forming json

```
$(document).on('click', '#YourID', function (e) {


    var PermissionDetails = [];
    $('tr.Permission td:not(:first-child) input:checked').each(function () {
        var ScreenID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('value');
        var ProjectRoleID = $(this).attr('value');
        var PermissionType = $(this).attr('name');
        PermissionDetails.push({ "ScreenID": ScreenID, "ProjectRoleID": ProjectRoleID, "PermissionType": PermissionType });

    });

});
```